# How to increase the number of /dev/mtd* in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In my linux /dev/ folder, I have mtd0 - mtd7 and mtdblock0 - mtdblock7. I want to have more mtd devices here. What should I change when building the kernel?

Thanks

Comment: this might get more traction in superuser

Comment: Thanks. I'll copy this to that sub-website as a backup.

Comment: While the device nodes are trivial, the actual mtd device partitions are typically **compiled** into the kernel, so it is beyond the realm of superuser.  Also, cross-posting within the SE network is prohibited.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to create spare/extra nodes for some reason.  You cannot do that for non-existent memory.  Each MTD partition (for which device nodes are created in **/dev**) that is specified in the Device Tree, kernel command line, board file or whatever has to refer to non-volatile memory that is accessible when the memory device is initialized.

Answer (score 3):

You need more mtd partitions. Upon boot, the kernel creates one mtd and one mtdblock under /dev for each. The MTD partitions are usually written in the board's BSP file. You can override that by passing the kernel a `mtdparts` option.

More info [here](http://free-electrons.com/blog/managing-flash-storage-with-linux/). Also mtdinfo and `/proc/mtd` describe the start-end of each partition and its name.

**EDIT**:
An example of the mtd partition table is in `arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap3beagle.c` for the beagleboard [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-omap3beagle.c).

```
static struct mtd_partition omap3beagle_nand_partitions[] = {
/* All the partition sizes are listed in terms of NAND block size */
{
    .name       = "X-Loader",
    .offset     = 0,
    .size       = 4 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
    .mask_flags = MTD_WRITEABLE,    /* force read-only */
},
{
    .name       = "U-Boot",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x80000 */
    .size       = 15 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
    .mask_flags = MTD_WRITEABLE,    /* force read-only */
},
{
    .name       = "U-Boot Env",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x260000 */
    .size       = 1 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
},
{
    .name       = "Kernel",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x280000 */
    .size       = 32 * NAND_BLOCK_SIZE,
},
{
    .name       = "File System",
    .offset     = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x680000 */
    .size       = MTDPART_SIZ_FULL,
},
```

};

There are 5 partitions mtd0 to mtd4 with sizes hard-coded in the Kernel image.

Comment: *"Upon boot, the kernel identifies the MTD partitions..."* -- Not accurate.  The kernel is provided with the partition information, typically through the kernel command line, or the Device Tree blob or even a hard-coded table.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks. Yeah the word "identifies" was not accurate, but I did mention the board's file and command line parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what is bsp file. In the info website, it shows how to list the partitions in the platform init code. It could also be done in the dts file. I try to list more than 8 mtd partitions, but during rebooting it shows that cannot find /dev/mtd8 /dev/mtd9 /dev/mtd10 etc....

Comment: Do you have the kernel source ? What board are you using ?

Comment: Also, how do you "list more than 8 mtd partitions" ?

Comment: @stcheng *"it shows how to list the partitions..."*  -- That's not simply a *"listing"* (i.e. display or show), but a means of specifying the partitions (i.e. it's configuration).

Comment: @stcheng Probably you are missing device nodes? If the command `mtdinfo` shows more devices than you can see device nodes in `/dev/mtd*` then you might want to call some `mknod` or adjust udev...